# Python Recursion - Finding sum of max and min in a nested array

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, nested

How do I use recursion to find the sum of the max and min values in a nested array? The recursion must loop through the array the least amount of times as possible. It's not possible to flatten the array.

Thanks in advance. This is the code I've written so far. It manages to do it for non nested arrays by flattening the list

Comment: Can you post what you are trying to do .. I mean the piece of code . or example you tried so far

Comment: Please give some examples of what you have tried and your starting data set

Comment: "This is the code I've written so far" - so... code?

Comment: What's the "sum of the max and min values"? Sum of max values and sum of min values? OK, max/min values of what? What's the nesting depth? Provide your input data and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the maximum value from a nested array, try:

```
def find_max(my_list):
    m = max([find_max(x) if type(x) is list else x for x in my_list])
    return m
```

See example: https://ideone.com/tcO6sY

The same goes for the minimum.